# How to do large-scale replacement/tokenization in R tm_map gsub from a list?

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining, tm, tidyr

Has anyone managed to create a massive find/replace function/working code snippet that exchanges out known bigrams in a dataframe?

Here's an example. I'm able to don onesie-twosie replacements but I really want to leverage a known lexicon of about 800 terms I want to find-replace to turn them into word units prior to DTM generation. For example, I want to turn "Google Analytics" into "google-analytics".

I know it's theoretically possible; essentially, a custom stopwords list functionally does almost the same thing, except without the replacement. And it seems stupid to just have 800 gsubs.

Here's my current code. Any help/pointers/URLs/RTFMs would be greatly appreciated.

```
mystopwords <- read.csv(stopwords.file, header = FALSE)
mystopwords <- as.character(mystopwords$V1)
mystopwords <- c(mystopwords, stopwords())

# load the file

df <- readLines(file.name)

# transform to corpus

doc.vec <- VectorSource(df)
doc.corpus <- Corpus(doc.vec)
# summary(doc.corpus)

## Hit known phrases

docs <- tm_map(doc.corpus, content_transformer(gsub), pattern = "Google Analytics", replacement = "google-analytics")

## Clean up and fix text - note, no stemming

doc.corpus <- tm_map(doc.corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
doc.corpus <- tm_map(doc.corpus, removePunctuation,preserve_intra_word_dashes = TRUE)
doc.corpus <- tm_map(doc.corpus, removeNumbers)
doc.corpus <- tm_map(doc.corpus, removeWords, c(stopwords("english"),mystopwords))
doc.corpus <- tm_map(doc.corpus, stripWhitespace)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **corpus** library allows you to combine multi-word phrases into single tokens. When there are multiple matches, it chooses the longest one:

```
library(corpus)
text_tokens("I live in New York City, New York",
            combine = c("new york city", "new york"))

# [[1]]
# [1] "i"             "live"          "in"            "new_york_city"
# [5] ","             "new_york"
```

By default, the connector is the underscore character (`_`), but you can specify an alternative connector using the `connector` argument`.

In your example, you could do the following to get a document-by-term matrix:

```
mycombine <- c("google analytics", "amazon echo") # etc.
term_matrix(doc.corpus, combine = mycombine,
            drop_punct = TRUE, drop_number = TRUE,
            drop = c(stopwords_en, mystopwords))
```

Note also that **corpus** keeps intra-word hyphens, so there's no need for a `preserve_intra_word_dashes` option.

It can be a hassle to specify the preprocessing options in every function call. If you'd like, you can convert your corpus to a *corpus_frame* (a data.frame with a special *text* column), then set the preprocessing options (the *text_filter*):

```
corpus <- as_corpus_frame(doc.corpus)
text_filter(corpus) <- text_filter(combine = mycombine,
                                   drop_punct = TRUE,
                                   drop_number = TRUE,
                                   drop = c(stopwords_en, mystopwords))
```

After that, you can just call

```
term_matrix(corpus)
```

There's a lot more information about **corpus**, including an introductory vignette, at http://corpustext.com